# how can I run AKKA StreamRefs sequentially?

Tags: java, akka, akka-stream

I'm using AKKA streamRefs (version 2.5.32), with java API.

I've tried to build a graph (using graphDSL or the PartitionHub classes) in which I can stream some data in a Round-Robin manner and upon its completion broadcasting all the servers a 'FINISH' message,
identifing the stream completion using `monitorMat` and `watchTermination` didn't work for me.

I used the AKKA documentation to build a graph in which I stream to multiple sinks some data as follows:

(using `watchTermination`)

```
RunnableGraph<Source<EventAccessCollection, NotUsed>> runnableGraph =
                source.toMat(PartitionHub.ofStateful(EventAccessCollection.class, () -> new RoundRobin<EventAccessCollection>(),
                        workersSinks.size()), Keep.right());
Source<EventAccessCollection, NotUsed> fromProducer = runnableGraph.run(mat);

for (Sink<EventAccessCollection, NotUsed> w:workersSinks) {
    fromProducer.runWith(w,mat);
}

fromProducer.watchTermination((
        (mat,completionStage)->
                completionStage.toCompletableFuture().thenRun(() -> {
            broadcastMessage(FINISH);

        })
));
```

The documentation can be found here:
https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5.32/stream/stream-dynamic.html

It seems that since SinkRef must be of the type `<T,NotUsed>` I can't use it to get feedback about the stream (as opposed to `CompletionStage<Done>`)

Another thought I had in mind was that maybe streaming/sending messages from different graphs can be defined sequentially so they will arrive to the recipents in the order in which they were sent.

How can I force order on the streams/messages which I want to send to the recipients?

Comment: What do you mean by "force the order"? Messages inside an akka stream graph are processed sequentially. Outside of an akka stream graph you have to decide using whatever logic you want.

Comment: Lets say you want to stream a collection of integers to multiple sinks and after that a collection of strings to the same sinks. How can you that? can you give an example please?

Comment: This example on the official akka stream doc (https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/operators/Broadcast.html) does a broadcast to 3 sinks named count, min, and max.